# exposed filter autocomplete suggestions sort

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have more than 10 terms in vocabulary: car, red car, blue car, yellow car etc.
I know that 10 results is hardcoded value for autocomplete widget. My problem is that after typing "car", I only get various other terms, simple "car" is not in suggestions.

How does the autocomplete widget work?
Is there any way how to sort/alter results? Why it does not show the exact term first "car" and then all other terms containing "car"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter handler class [`views_handler_filter_term_node_tid`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21taxonomy%21views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc/class/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid/7.x-3.x) uses the autocomplete path **admin/views/ajax/autocomplete/taxonomy** and is driven by the callback [`views_ajax_autocomplete_taxonomy()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!ajax.inc/function/views_ajax_autocomplete_taxonomy/7.x-3.x).

This autocomplete callback explicitly excludes the term typed in and doesn't do any explicit sorting (thus defaults to whatever your RDBMS does):

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
$query->addTag('translatable');
$query->addTag('term_access');

// Do not select already entered terms.
if (!empty($tags_typed)) {
  $query->condition('t.name', $tags_typed, 'NOT IN');
}
// Select rows that match by term name.
$tags_return = $query
->fields('t', array('tid', 'name'))
  ->condition('t.vid', $vid)
  ->condition('t.name', '%' . db_like($tag_last) . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAllKeyed();
```

If you'd like to alter the results or how it's sorted, the query is using [tagging](https://www.drupal.org/node/310077), thus available for altering via [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x).

Comment: HI, thank you for explanation. It is weird that the query explicitly excludes the term typed, though.

Comment: The field accepts comma delimited list of fields. I think the design is meant not to suggest a terms already entered after a user types it out.